# Soundcloud Widget API optimization for better SEO and ranking

Tags: optimization, soundcloud

I am embedding soundcloud into my website. Something like this:

```
iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="yes" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/160479232&amp;color=123456&amp;theme_color=000000&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

My problem is when I run [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) against my site it shows that all soundcloud images for artwork and avatars are not getting compressed.  Therefore, lowering my site score and SEO ranking.

According to [Soundcloud Support](https://developers.soundcloud.com/support) developer questions are answered here on stack overflow.  I would like to know how I can improve my site ranking and SEO score when using this method to load up soundcloud tracks?

Perhaps I can convince you to enable compression on your soundcloud servers.  Here's what pagespeed is showing me:

Optimize the following images to reduce their size by 55.4KiB (24% reduction).

1. Compressing
   https://i1.sndcdn.com/…rtworks-000097343489-e5oh8i-t500x500.jpg
   could save 16.9KiB (28% reduction). Compressing
   https://i1.sndcdn.com/…rtworks-000097343489-e5oh8i-t500x500.jpg
   could save 16.9KiB (28% reduction). Compressing
   https://i1.sndcdn.com/…avatars-000096472169-lpvczz-t500x500.jpg
   could save 7.4KiB (23% reduction). Compressing
   https://i1.sndcdn.com/…rtworks-000139938442-ab4a2g-t500x500.jpg
   could save 5.1KiB (16% reduction). Compressing
   https://i1.sndcdn.com/…rtworks-000139938442-ab4a2g-t500x500.jpg
   could save 5.1KiB (16% reduction).

Comment: Hi Soundcloud support.  Here is [PageSpeed Tools > PageSpeed Modules] (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/?csw=1) that is available to install on your servers.  This is a win-win for you and your developers.  I am still waiting to receive optimized images when I use your widget.

Comment: This appears to be a request to SoundCloud to enable a particular feature, rather than a question that can be answered by the community.